# AI Design for a Card Game

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am currently working on an AI for the Card Game [Wizard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizard_%28card_game%29). 
Wizard is a trick-taking game, in which each player states how many tricks he believes he will take, before the actual game begins.

After reading some papers and some parts of the book [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137903952), I decided to first design my algorithm for the game with open cards, so that each players has complete imformation.
So I just started and implemented a Monte Carlo Tree Search algorithm, using UCB Selection Policy. I have implemented everything in java, and it seems to be running pretty well, but my bots are not playing optimal yet. Especially predicting the tricks you get seems to be a hard task, for which I used the same MCTS as for the playing.

So basically my algorithm expands the current state of the game (e.g. 2 players have placed their bid) creating one new node (e.g. 3 players have placed their bid), and then just plays randomly until the game is over. Then the scores are evaluated and backed up trough the nodes.

I think the next step to improve the algorithm would be, to add some heuristic to the tree search, so that branches that will most likely result in a loss will be ignored from the start.

My question is: Do you think that this a good approach? What other approaches would be promising, or do you have any other tipps?

Comment: I know this game as "screw your neighbour". I believe you can come up with fairly good play simply by considering how many cards are higher than  yours. Assume a one-card game: if you had the ace of trump, your likelihood for one trick is 100%, whereas if you had any ace of non-trump, you can consider that as ~25% (or ~50% if you anticipate leading, but to know that you might start using a tree search... would also allow you to figure out the percentages more accurately by knowing the probability of cards left in play when you expect to play a particular card).

Comment: You may have better luck over at the Computer Science StackExchange site, if you just want feedback on your algorithm instead of on the actual coding/implementation of it.

Comment: I've been hoping to investigate MCTS for card-playing games, since it seems such a good fit. It's interesting that you're not seeing great results. Your idea to add some heuristics to the card-play seems to still be in keeping with the spirit of MCTS and one would think it would help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the game but I can give you general advice. Monte Carlo approach is a good solution if

- The search space is very huge (i.e Go board game)
- You don't know how to build a strong heuristic

With these conditions MCTS is the best that you can do.

But **if you are able to build a strong heuristic function** than you have to go straight with "Min-Max/Alpha-Beta Pruning" algorithm (or similar ones). In general with these algorithms you get stronger AIs.

This is the reason because with GO we use MCTS but with Chess we still use Min-Max.

But the algorithm is just 10% of the AI. The most difficult (and beautiful) part of game-AI programming is to exploit game mechanics to prune search space and build the strongest heuristic :)

For example you can start to understand AI from a well-known card game: Poker (http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~games/poker/). Then you can extend these techniques to your Game.

Comment: But how would you handle imperfect imformation? The space of possible deals is huge, and I am not sure anymore, if I will get good results by first trying to approach the problem with perfect imformation, and then just add Monte Carlo Sampling. My first plan was to use Monte Carlo Sampling to generate a possible deals, and solve each deal by using MCTS. The best move can then be calculated by averaging over all the samples. But i don't think, this will yield good results in reasonable time.

Comment: Well, maybe you don't have to check every possible deal. For instance in Poker AI thanks to game-theory and other statistical approach we are able to avoid to check "every possible deal". These optimizations depend strictly on the game.